# When my husband opens his Mac my account appears

Tags: macbook-pro

How can My husband stop my account appearing when he opens his Mac instead of his own appearing without having to change the user

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Automatic Login quite easily:

1. Open System Preferences (accessible from the  menu).
2. Click Users & Groups.

   [image]
3. Click the padlock in the bottom-left corner and enter your password.

   [image]
4. Click “Login Options”.

   [image]
5. Set “Automatic login:” to “Off”.

[image: Users & Groups preference pane]